# How to push an array in a std vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am doing some height map in OpenGL. The only z of each vertex is stored in a file, and I have to store as well the x and y value in a vector :

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<float>      _data;
    float constexpr         triangle_side(1.118033989);
    std::ifstream           ifs("mymap");
    std::string             line;

    if (not ifs.is_open())
        return -1;
    for (float y(0) ; std::getline(ifs, line) ; --y)
    {
        std::istringstream  iss(line);

        for (float x(static_cast<int>(y) % 2 ? 0 : triangle_side / 2), z ; iss >> z ; x += triangle_side)
            _data.push_back({x, y, z}); // does not compile
    }
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, it is a bad thing to do : `_data.push_back(x); _data.push_back(y); _data.push_back(z);` because the vector perhaps will reallocate the array at each call.

What is the best way to do it ?

If I do :

```
std::vector< std::array<float, 3> > _data;
//...
_data.push_back({x, y, z});
```

is it guaranteed the values will all be contiguous ?

Comment: If you know the final size of the vector you can `reserve` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato I do not know it because the size of the map is not fixed. It depends on the used file.

Comment: @Boiethios, ok, so you can use std::array or Joachim answer (reserve n+3 slots at every loop)

Comment: Anyway, if memory is not a problem, reserving more space than needed will give a boost, especially in this case.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato Memory is always a problem. Calculation speed still follows Moore's law, memory speed hasn't and never will.

Comment: I mean, instead of reserving size+3 at each loop, you can allocate size+300 every 100 loop. Or you can always reserve the minimun (or the mean) length of the final vector. In this case, reserving some unnecessary kb is better than continuosly reallocating if you have GB of memory.

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato I'll think about it, it seems to be a great idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::array<float, 3>` is laid out like a C array in memory, so the `float`s will be contiguous. You could also just use `insert`:

```
_data.insert(_data.cend(), {x, y, z});
```

Comment: Wow, this is cool. I looked in the `stl_vector.h` and saw : `iterator insert(const_iterator __position, initializer_list<value_type> __l)` It is a good solution, and I wonder how it is possible the standard does not have a `void push_back(initializer_list<value_type> __l)`

Comment: @Boiethios you should check with cppreference.com in the future. It's much easier than going through header files.

Comment: Look at emplace_back http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato `emplace_back` does not accept initializer list

Comment: `emplace_back` won't try to insert 3 `float`s. It will try to construct a single `float` from three arguments and insert it, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::vector::reserve(size_type n) to reserve that the backing array contain at least n elements. If it does not, it will be reallocated once.
On an existing vector, if you need not just '3' but 'at least 3 more' elements, you just call it with (std::vector::size + 3). After that you can push back safely  with the guarantee the array won't be reallocated inside the vector.

A vector of std::array is forced to be contiguous by the standard, as is std::vector. A std::vector of std::arrays thus has all the elements in contiguous order. [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

@cin_cout:
C++03 (23.2.4.1):

> The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is
>   a vector where T is some type other than bool, then it obeys the
>   identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I will use this second solution. I was a little afraid using a container of containers. I think it can lead to some mess I cannot understand...

Comment: It can, but the memory guarantee is there.